# How C++ can import a DLL made in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, dllimport

I have a DLL made in C#, this DLL contains some clases like Creator.

I need to load this DLL and use Creator class in C++ unmanaged,

so Is there some way to create that instance or must I load just the functions exposed?

I need something like this:

```
CreatorInstance->Init();
```

Is this posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Fisher's approach using C++/CLI is by far the easiest means of handling this, but it is not the only means.

The other three options are:

1) Use COM interop to wrap the .NET class via COM

2) You can host the CLR in your native, unmanaged application, and call into it.  For details, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx).

3) You can host the Mono runtime, and use it to call your managed code.  For details on this, [see this page](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono).

Option 2 and 3 are very similar, but IMO, 3 is easier than 2.

Comment: Thanks.

I can't switch to cls, I must use native code.
about your options:
1-I have the DLL already as a COM but I want to find another way to do that.
2 and 3- How they work?

Comment: Your comment doesn't indicate whether you clearly understood the clr suggestion.  You can't turn on the /CLR switch?  Is this just too difficult?

If you turn on /clr, you are mixing native with managed.  It's not a complete switch over.

Comment: My problem is a client requirement, it should not be /CLR, it just be native. It is not my choice.

Answer (score 4):

Most of what you need can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k%28VS.80%29.aspx

Primarily, you need to learn about the /clr switch for C++ compilation.  Then you need to understand the C++ extensions that Microsoft added to allow for mixed assemblies.  (A C++ "pointer" to a managed class would use p^ instead of p*, and so on.)

Comment: There must be a typelib-import way of doing this, no?

Comment: If you were dealing with COM objects, than you could use a typelib.  As Reed Copsey suggested below, that is an option.

You indicated in a comment below that you can't switch to CLR because you "must use native code".  These options are not exclusive.  Microsoft specifically designed C++ as the language to use when you needed to get managed and unmanaged code talking together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting article on how you should be able to accomplish this without using the /CLR option

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx

Works pretty well.

Comment: interop is dirt slow but far better than clr

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is possible and you do not "have" to use CLI or the /clr switch. Using the good old COM architecture you can do it pretty easily http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx. Understanding the way COM works might be the biggest challenge here, but it's usefull once you know it.